# PHP Simple HTML DOM cell value

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have a problem parsing with PHP Simple HTML DOM -lib.

HTML:

```
<td>
<span>text</span>
actual text i want to pick up
<span>text2</span>
</td>
```

I dont know how to get the "actual text i want to pick up" -part from that.
$node->innertext and $node->plaintext have the text inside the span-tags aswell.

edit:
I have tried

```
$node->innertext // prints the whole thing
$node->plaintext // prints "textactual text i want to pick uptext"
$node->tag //prints td
```

The manual doesnt seem to give any clear mention for a case like mine.

If there is a better way to parse html than that library, I am open to other suggestions aswell. I have mostly gotten what I want with that library, but this text I havent been able to pick up.

Comment: Please show what you've tried by editing your question.

Comment: simple html dom is a (in my eyes *very*) limited, broken and flawed componend. I'd assume that what you're looking for is not even easily possible with simple html dom. So why do you expect that that library would be able to do what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured how to access the needed information. Tried different combinations about $node->children($x)->innertext, but that didnt help. This way doesnt feel "right", but works in my case.

```
foreach($node->nodes as $c) {
   if($c->tag == "text")
     $text = $c->innertext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_get_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) the following

```
$source = '<td>
<span>text</span>
actual text i want to pick up
<span>text2</span>
</td>';

$dom = str_get_html($source);
var_dump($dom->plaintext);
```

Output

```
text actual text i want to pick up text2
```

Comment: The OP only wants `actual text i want to pick up`

Comment: Yeah, I have tried similar approach, but as mentioned, it gives too much text. I dont want the stuff inside span-tags.